# Dropdown menu open in middle main menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, nav

I have a menu with drop down list, when mouse hover the main menus item then dropdown menu list open with dis-align like depend on then main menu items like ( Home - MyServiceItems - Blog - MyProducts etc ) some where dropdown list come in middle some where right side, I would like to my drop down menu comes middle under the main menu. Thanks in advance.

```css
header.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 11;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  background-color: #00666a;
}

header.header .main--header-wrap {
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb*/
}

.header-login-section {
  background-color: #009297;
  padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
  display: none;
}

header.header .main--header-wrap .main--header-main {
  /*padding: 15px 0*/
}

header.header .main--header-wrap .main--header-main ul.social--icons li {
  padding-right: 15px
}

header.header .main--header-wrap .main--header-main ul.social--icons li a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #fff
}

header.header .main--header-wrap .main--header-main ul.social--icons li a:hover {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffc20e;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

header.header .main--header-wrap .main--header-main ul.social--icons li:last-child {
  /*padding-right: 0*/
}

header.header .main--header-wrap .main--header-main .moelogo {
  max-width: 170px
}

header.header .main--header-wrap .main--header-main .siilogo {
  max-width: 200px
}

header.header .menu_navbar .menu--navbar-inner {
  padding: 15px 0
}

header.header .menu_navbar .menu--navbar-inner li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: relative
}

header.header .menu_navbar .menu--navbar-inner li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-right: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

header.header .menu_navbar .menu--navbar-inner .navigation li a:hover {
  color: #ffc20e;
}

header.header .menu_navbar .menu--navbar-inner .navigation li a:hover:after {
  width: 10%;
  /*left: 0;*/
  color: #ffc20e;
}

header.header .menu_navbar .menu--navbar-inner .navigation li:last-child a {
  margin-right: 0
}

header.header .menu_navbar .menu--navbar-inner .navigation li .dropdown-down {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #009297;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -78px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 13.5px rgb(34 33 33 / 20%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 13.5px rgb(34 33 33 / 20%);
}

header.header .menu_navbar .menu--navbar-inner .navigation li .dropdown-down li {
  font-size: .938em;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu_navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu--navbar-inner">
      <li><a href="#">Main Manu</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-down">
          <li><a href="plan-your-budget.html">Sub Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="visa.html">Sub Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="travel.html">Sub Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="domestic-travel.html">Sub Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="local-support.html">Sub Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is that all your css Are you sure ?

Comment: Is that huge chunk of CSS realy necessary to show the issue? This doesn't look like a [**minimal** reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)...

Comment: It's not clear to me what do you want - i barely understand your text. And where is the question?